# Why do I have to AJAX things not in constructor() but in componentDidMount()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, lifecycle

Why do I need to use componentDidMount for async or ajax? For componentWillMount, I understand that this is because whatever changes occur in componentWillMount, there is a problem that cannot be re-rendering. But in the case of a constructor, wouldn't it be re-rendering if there was a change?

And the reason I thought about it in my own way, is that if you do async in the constructor, it's probably because it's going to take a lot of first rendering time, and it's going to take a lot of time to load the pages. Is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**let's assume that Api call happend in Component Will mount/constructor**

The Async call is fired in CWM/Constructor and other lines of this function will start executing, Once those functions are done, the render function will start executing and assuming 50% of render function is executed, In the mean time you got the response from the async call you made in CWM/constructor, Now you will call setState which triggers the **updation cycle**to update the data but the skeleton html itself is not ready(as the render function is not completed) where will the data goes and updates ?

It's completly waste of first execution of render function. Instead of this let the render function get complete which in turn html object is constructed and then can update the data.

In simple terms, We need to build the house and move in, instead we moving on to the empty plot and start building house. The second one is also possible but not comfortable.

From the question, It looks like you are confused between constructor and CWM, there is no difference between the two, Because of that react has removed CWM in the latest version to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. As you say, I was going to start building a house lying in an empty space!